# Keycloak redirect to previous page

Tags: angular, keycloak

I have a login page where users can click on button **login** or on button **register** in material dialog.
This page is public, and if user clicks on button **LOGIN** I redirect him to route `home`

```
this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
```

And there, on `home` is keycloak authentification.

But problem is, after successfully login, user is still on previous page (where he clicked on button LOGIN).

Is there any way to fix this?

```
import { KeycloakService } from "keycloak-angular";
import { AppConfigService } from "app-config/app-config.service";

export function initializer(
  keycloak: KeycloakService,
  appConfigService: AppConfigService
): () => Promise<any> {
  return (): Promise<any> => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      await appConfigService.loadAppConfig();
      try {
        await keycloak.init({
          config: appConfigService.getConfig("keycloak"),
          initOptions: {
            onLoad: "check-sso",
            checkLoginIframe: false
          },
          enableBearerInterceptor: false,
          bearerExcludedUrls: ["registration$", ]
        });
        resolve();
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error);
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Thnx

Answer (score 2):

This is late but because no one answer this question so I'll try to explain how to do it. I'm not familiar with Angular but I did it in reactjs. The important thing is we focus on the "keycloak-js" library, which will be used in either framework. It may not close to what you expected but you can do the same.

- Step 1: When the user clicks to the private route, then you redirect him to the page with login button. In the URL, you need to add a param that specifies where to redirect after login success: Ex: http://localhost:3000/login?redirectUrl={encodedSecuredPath}
- Step 2: In the login page, you have a login button and you use keycloak.login() on the "onClick" event of this button. At this time, after user login successful the page will be redirect to: http://localhost:3000/
- Step 3: Pass the object {redirectUri:{http://localhost:3000/+{decodedSecuredPath}}} to keycloak.login(object). Then keycloak will do the rest.

You can learn more about the param of keycloak.login() in this link:
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#login-options